# PHP json_decode data format

Tags: php, json

my json data that names are between **("")** is working as following.

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}', true));
```

but names are not between **("")** is not working:

```
var_dump(json_decode('{a:"foo",b:"bar"}', true)) ;
```

my json data is coming from another server like this:

```
{a:"foo",b:"bar"}
```

and that json created by php with json_encode.

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
return json_encode($rows)
```

but json_decode returning NULL for this object.

Comment: That's not JSON then, but JavaScript Object Literals (JSOL). PHPs plain json_decode() does not support it. Use a more specific parser, or one of the unreliable patch workarounds.

Comment: but that is created by json_encode.

Comment: No, it's certainly not. Two alternatives: [How to parse this json with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238138)

Comment: ok thanks your answer validated my json

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you will have to modify the string before parsing it because that isn't valid JSON.  You can check it with a site like this.

http://jsonlint.com/